# How can I decode the RSA encryption more efficiently?

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption, rsa

For a project I'm decoding the RSA encryption. My code works perfectly, but the check I can do, says its too slow.

I've tested the algorithm and I've concluded that the bottleneck is in the following code:

```
message = (c**d) % n
```

Without this, the code runs instantaneously. c is the encrypted message, d is the Modular multiplicative inverse and n = pq.
the encrypted message is 783103, so I get that I'm dealing with large numbers, but now it takes around 1 seconds to run. Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Python's built-in pow() (exponentiation) function [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) takes an optional third argument, the modulus.

That should fix your problem.

This is from [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)